# Time at the big-bang

Tags: time, big-bang

At the moment of the big-bang there were no particles with positive rest mass. What is the meaning to aspeak of time then (as a clock can be created only with particles with mass).

Comment: Who made the rule about clocks being made of particles?  And the Copenhagen interpretation of QM does not apply to time, only particles.

Comment: The fact that different clocks agree suggests that they are measuring something that does not depend on clocks.

Comment: *At the moment of the big-bang there were no particles with positive rest mass.* Where did you get this idea? This is false.

Answer (score 2):

While time can be considered a subjective dimension (it is different to observers on different frames), time is our understanding of the chain of cause-consequences throughout systems, so you can't expect to measure time during the big bang, but to interpret time as the point during the sequence (if something like that is factually possible).

If you see a chain of dominoes, take a picture on the middle of the process, and you can estimate what was the exact time when the picture was taken, of course, by knowing the time between each domino pair interaction, the time it hits the next, and the initial time. You can use the same idea to understand the big bang, I think (I just know the basics)

I write about systems and interaction theories, and a fundamental approach of my writing is that 1) systems have inputs and outputs, and they don't mix (although in reality, a membrane can act as input and output channel); 2)there's always a process, change, between i/o channels, a delay, which is our understanding of time. Then, the time row is generated by the internal processing of systems.

Then, where change exists, time exists. And it is relative to the observer. Therefore, time is always a subjective notion. Using a clock is just making correlations with perceptible changes. If we are unable to perceive change (even if it occurs) we lose the time notion, even on mathematics. That's the exact experience of a person in jail, with no sunlight, and only silence. Having no changes to observe, a prisoner may feel the notion of time disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

Massless particles still can only travel at c, so time still exists. It is needed to define the causal structure of spacetime, even if it is miniuscule. Time is not clocks with springs, time is anything that changes, and if there were no time all particles would be everywhere at once - how do you then deal with cause and effect?

Also needed to define the then expansion of the universe, how would the universe change in time? Or, use the radius of the universe expanding to define some measure of time. or use the density of massless particles becoming lower, as the universe expands.

You could even argue that even without massless particles, if somehow the universe didn't have them, the dark energy which is some property of vacuum also helps define time as it causes the expansion of the universe, again a measurable quantity.

And if you argue that there are no clocks, there are also no rulers, yet space also exists

Hopefully this is enough reason that if there are any of the entities we know something about there was a space and a time.

The real problem is when you get to Planck lengths and times, there are no particles then, just whatever has Planck sizes. (Whatever the elementary entity of quantum gravity is), and probably it is a pre-spatial quantum foam with a pre-time interval. Spacetime is not believed to be the same at those sizes and time intervals.

Comment: Massless particles (because traveling at c) cannot "experience" time , nor space. This  is the reason of my question: what is the meaning  of time in a massless Universe?

Comment: What do you mean traveling at c if no space and time? If no space and time what does velocity mean? Can't have it both ways.

Comment: According to Relativity time slows down  and distance srinks as speed approaches the maximum speed  of causality ( c ). So for massless particles such as photons, time and distance does not exists - they are only created and destroyed, with no possibility of any change in "between".  So again - what measures time in a universe in which all particles are massless and  cannot change (change implies time)?

Comment: A photon is not everywhere. They do have to live in light like hyper surfaces, but light like hyper surfaces have spatial and time coordinates (draw a st diagram, draw the 45 degree hypercones, they have light like and other trajectories, and spatial  and time coordinates change. It is true they are related such as x-ct=0 but there is change. You're saying so alike and timeline trajectories don't exist so in the light like coordinates u=x-ct does not change. Irrelevant, there could be other trajectories in that space time. Over cosmological time radiation will freeze into particles with mass

Comment: Photons and other massless particles will occasionally interact and in some of those massive particles emerge. There may be a thermodynamic equilibrium where it is almost all radiation, but you can't stop those interactions, at any nonzero temperature.